# Insert characters (hyphens) between matches in RegEx

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am using Regular Expressions to find very simple patterns.

However, I want to insert a hyphen character between the matches.

I'm very familiar with writing RegEx Match patterns, but struggling with how to use RegEx replace to insert characters.

My RegEx is:
**(\d{1,2})([A-Z]{1,3})(_)?(\d{3,4})**
which matches:

- 03EM0109
- 03EM0112
- 03EM0151
- 3V204
- 02SDV_0900

I would like the output, using RegEx Replace, to input hyphens between the matches to give me:

- 03-EM-0109
- 03-EM-0112
- 03-EM-0151
- 3-V-204
- 02-SDV-0900

I tried changing the RegEx and entering numbered capture groups for null patterns between, but when using a replace function this returns only hyphens.  Presumably because the null capture group is not actually capturing anything?

Using:
**(\d{1,2})()([A-Z]{1,3})()(_)?()(\d{3,4})**

And replacing with **$2-$4-$5-** 
Returns 3 hyphens **- - -**

Could someone please help....

Comment: `(\d{1,2})([A-Z]{1,3})_?(\d{3,4})` -> `$1-$2-$3` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WZPcjD/1))

Comment: See this: https://regex101.com/r/4rCCti/1

Comment: Thanks, I can see where my problem is.  I was testing it on just the first numbered capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the RegExp `(\d{1,2})([A-Z]{1,3})_?(\d{3,4})`, and replace with `$1-$2-$3` then it seems to produce the desired results. I removed the capture group around the underscore

Comment: Thanks Lebster, was it the capture group around the underscore causing the problem?

Comment: It was that and your empty capture groups. You were replacing each match with 2 empty groups separated by dashes (resulting in 2 dashes), and then the underscore if it was there, but nothing if it wasn't.